# Correct way to export a class with flow?

Tags: javascript, class, flowtype

After having updated my flow-bin package from 0.142.0 to 0.143.1, I got hundreds of error messages like this one (signature-verification-failure):
[image]

I know this version of flow made types-first the default mode but still, I don't understand since all of my functions are properly annotated, like in this simple class:

```
/* @flow */

export class Foo {

  bar = (n: number): number => n + 1;

}
```

I also tried `export default Foo` and `module.exports = Foo` but got the same result.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow wants explicit type annotation on `bar`:

```
export class Foo {
  bar: (n: number) => number = n => n + 1;
}
```

You can use [annotate-exports](https://flow.org/en/docs/cli/annotate-exports/) codemod, to fill some of the missing annotations automatically.